mounting passwordless SMB share results in permission denied error
Here's what I did:
mkdir /mnt/shared
mount -v -t cifs //192.168.1.128/shared /mnt/shared

When I do that I'm prompted for a password. When I just hit enter (since the share I'm trying to connect to is passwordless) I get this:
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=192.168.1.128,unc=\\192.168.1.128\shared,user=root,pass=*******
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messges (dmesg)
mount: (hint) your fstab has been modified, but systemd still uses
       the old version; use 'systemctl daemon-reload' to reload,

Any ideas?

Here is what I include in my /etc/fstab username=<name>,password=<pwd>,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 replace  with your user name and  with "" (a null string) to see if that works.

@graham - My /etc/fstab now has //192.168.1.128/shared /mnt/shared cifs username=neubert,password="",rw,uid=1000,guid=1000 at the bottom of it. I did systemctl daemon-reload and then tried mount -v -t cifs //192.168.1.128/shared /mnt/shared and got the same mount error(13): Permission denied. I tried replacing  username=neubert,password="" with guest and got the same result.

@graham - and either of the /etc/fstab variants the mount options mount -v -t cifs //192.168.1.128/shared /mnt/shared both show user=root. Like it doesn't seem like /etc/fstab is being referenced so it's unclear to me why it was even showing that /etc/fstab message at the end...

hmm odd. The full line of my fstab entry is //192.168.1.117/<share_name> /media/NAS/<share_name> cifs username=<user_name>,password=<pswd>,rw,uid=1000,gid=500 and that works perfectly. As you have no password for your share, I just thought that an empty string might work but what happens if you use your login password instead?

Install nmap sudo apt install nmap then edit your original post and include the output of this command: nmap -Pn --script smb-protocols 192.168.1.128

@Morbius1 - sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared apparently works so it's hard to imagine nmap being anything other than a waste of my time. Try again.

there's absolutely no need to be obtuse. If the suggestion doesn't work (it works on my instance) then at least something else has been discounted in your quest for a solution. Sometimes, things require trial and error to accomplish which is why AU is so useful. I suggested your user password but thinking about it, the user password to log in to the system is quite apart from any password for access to the CIFS share. I went through a number of command iterations to get success in my case.
