unable to auto-mount path even tho i can mount it using mount command
I can successfully mount an SMB share if I do this:
sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared

Like if I do that and go to /media/shared in the File Explorer I can view the contents of the mount point.
Putting this into my /etc/fstab, however, does not result in /media/shared being auto-mounted when I start the computer up:
//192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared cifs username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000

No problem, I thought, I'll just put the mount command into my ~/.bashrc. If I just put it in my ~/.bashrc file without some sort of if statement, however, it'll give me errors whenever that location is already mounted so I tried this:
if mount -l | grep -q 192.168.1.128
then
   sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared
fi

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Like even if I put that in a standalone test.sh file nothing is mounted, which just seems strange to me given that this reliably tells me if 192.168.1.128 is mounted or not:
if mount -l | grep -q 192.168.1.128
then
   echo "OK";
else
   echo "NOT OK";
fi

Any ideas?

What error or message do you get in syslog from the fstab mount (or when you do sudo mount -a? Also have you seen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/157128/proper-fstab-entry-to-mount-a-samba-share-on-boot

hmmm why did you delete your previous question on this when there were comments and questions you failed to answer? Are we expected to revisit this asking the same questions over?

@graham - in the previous question I didn't know that sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared worked. I was trying /etc/fstab stuff exclusively. The only outstanding question was about the output of nmap but that seems hardly relevant since, as sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared demonstrates I am able to connect. I suppose I could post that as an answer but it's not really an answer even if it does render the comment kinda pointless.

@graham - but if it strikes your fancy I can just delete this question and only post the bit wherein I'm asking why the if statement thing doesn't work. I mean, I'm liable to get comments about why I'm doing that vs /etc/fstab but, regardless, in-so-far as I know, the if statement approach should still work and it isn't

@graham - see https://askubuntu.com/q/1521683/180177 . Maybe you should go on a down voting spree and down vote that one too now!

@codlord - sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=neubert,password=whatever //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared gives me a mount: bad usage error. Works fine without the -a, however. And, in any event, it seems a bit strange that adding a new argument to mount would do anything, anyway, since the command, outside of the if statement and without that argument works great?

who said I downvoted this question? I merely pointed out that deleting a question only to ask the same question again is not best practice on Ask Ubuntu and is discouraged.

@graham - it's not the same question. If it were then this question should be closed as a dupe of the other (now re-opened) question. I mean, I suppose I could have edited the other question to turn it into a completely different question but, personally, I think that, in that scenario, you're better off just posting a new question.

Isn't your logic inverted? mount -l | grep -q 192.168.1.128 returns TRUE if the device is already mounted - presumably you want to run sudo mount ... if it is not mounted? However placing a command that needs sudo inside your ~/.bashrc is not the best approach imho.

Read man mount and add the "_netdev" option to your /etc/fstab entry.

Please click the checkmark to "accept" my answer, if it solved your problem, and might help others.

I appended ,_netdev to my /etc/fstab entry so that now it looks like //192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared cifs username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,_netdev and then rebooted and I'm not seeing the mount.


//192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared cifs
username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000

The reason an explicit mount works and an fstab does not is likely a timing problem. The network stack isn't fully operational at the time fstab is read by the system so the fstab declaration does nothing.
The suggestion by @codlord to run "sudo mount -a" after you login was a way to verify if that was happening. You added a "-a" option instead of running the command as is.
One way around this issue is to use a systemd automount: x-systemd.automount
//192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared cifs username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount

Note: I recommend changing your mount point to something under /mnt for best results and a better chance of success using this method:
//192.168.1.128/shared /mnt/shared cifs username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,x-systemd.automount

ALTERNATE METHOD
** Unmount the share:
sudo umount /media/shared

** Change the line in fstab to this:
//192.168.1.128/shared /media/shared cifs username=neubert,password=whatever,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,noauto,user 0 0

** Make systemd happy:
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

** Mount with this command:
mount /media/shared

No sudo required.
You can use "mount /media/shared" in your script -- OR -- you can open a file manager and click on the mount icon on the left side panel to mount.

Appending ,x-systemd.automount and then rebooting didn't help. Neither did appending ,x-systemd.automount,_netdev. I also tried appending both versions to /mnt/shared (or rather an altered /etc/ftab entry containing /mnt/shared vs /media/shared) and it didn't make a difference

Please see ALTERNATE METHOD above. Running out of options here. You may want to look at your entire fstab for any typos or redundancies.
